# ubiquity automatic install stops at keyboard layout chooser

Tags: ubuntu, installation, automation

I am trying to automate an Ubuntu (12.04.1 64bit) installation using ubiquity & preseed on a desktop live cd. It almost works fine. I edited the `txt.cfg` and added

```
label unattended
menu label ^Unattended installation
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append  file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz   quiet  splash noprompt  --
```

[This is my custom.seed file](http://paste.ubuntuusers.de/410387/)

The problem is that the installer shows the keyboard layout chooser and I have to click `next`. The correct language & keyboard layout (german) are already preselected.

What am I missing, or what's wrong in my custom.seed file, to automate the next click?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late reply. I am posting this because I also faced the same problem during automated ubuntu installation, and I hope this may help someone.

I have added `console-setup/layoutcode=en` (this is for English) in the `txt.cfg`, so that it looks like this:

```
label unattended
menu label ^Unattended installation
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append  file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper console-setup/layoutcode=en initrd=/casper/initrd.lz   quiet  splash noprompt  --
```

Also, to make the installer autochoose the default option and start installing after a timeout, add this line to isolinux/isolinux.cfg (in all versions).

`timeout 10`

Timeout values are in tenths of a second, therefore a timeout value of 10 is equal to one second.

I got this information from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization#Changing_isolinux.cfg_to_identify_your_preseed)

Regards,